# Problem with creating an object in neo4j

Tags: django, neo4j, neo4j.py

I am using the django integration for neo4j and I'm getting the following traceback when I'm trying to create a node.
I do have JPype installed and it can be imported.

```
 p = Person.objects.create(first_name='omer', last_name='katz')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 138, in create
    return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/model/django_model/__init__.py", line 362, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_util.py", line 47, in __get__
    method, graphdb = self.descr_get(obj, cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_util.py", line 41, in descr_get
    graphdb = self.accessor.__get__(obj, cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/model/django_model/__init__.py", line 58, in __get__
    return DjangoNeo.neo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/model/django_model/__init__.py", line 124, in neo
    return self.__setup_neo()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/model/django_model/__init__.py", line 136, in __setup_neo
    self.__neo = NeoService(resource_uri, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/__init__.py", line 522, in __new__
    neo = core.load_neo(resource_uri, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_core.py", line 180, in load_neo
    backend.initialize(**parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/__init__.py", line 61, in initialize
    raise ImportError("No applicable backend found.")
ImportError: No applicable backend found.
```

EDIT:
As requested here are my neo4j settings:

```
NEO4J_RESOURCE_URI = '/var/neo4j/neo4django'
# NEO4J_RESOURCE_URI should be the path to where
#    you want to store the Neo4j database.

NEO4J_OPTIONS = {
    # this is optional and can be used to specify
    # extra startup parameters for Neo4j, such as
    # the classpath to load Neo4j from.
}
```

EDIT:
After following thobe's suggestion I get the following when I try to import my own models:

```
    ERROR:root:Importing native backends failed.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/__init__.py", line 51, in initialize
        embedded, remote = implementation.initialize(classpath, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/reflection.py", line 44, in initialize
        jvm = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_core.py", line 96, in getDefaultJVMPath
        return _linux.getDefaultJVMPath()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 36, in getDefaultJVMPath
        jvm = _getJVMFromJavaHome()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 55, in _getJVMFromJavaHome
        if os.path.exists(java_home+"/bin/javac") :
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
    ERROR:root:Importing native backends failed.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      FERROR:root:Importing native backends failed.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/__init__.py", line 51, in initialize
        embedded, remote = implementation.initialize(classpath, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/reflection.py", line 44, in initialize
        jvm = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_core.py", line 96, in getDefaultJVMPath
        return _linux.getDefaultJVMPath()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 36, in getDefaultJVMPath
        jvm = _getJVMFromJavaHome()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 55, in _getJVMFromJavaHome
        if os.path.exists(java_home+"/bin/javac") :
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
    ERROR:root:Importing native backends failed.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/__init__.py", line 51, in initialize
        embedded, remote = implementation.initialize(classpath, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/reflection.py", line 44, in initialize
        jvm = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_core.py", line 96, in getDefaultJVMPath
        return _linux.getDefaultJVMPath()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 36, in getDefaultJVMPath
        jvm = _getJVMFromJavaHome()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 55, in _getJVMFromJavaHome
        if os.path.exists(java_home+"/bin/javac") :
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
    ERROR:root:Importing native backends failed.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/__init__.py", line 51, in initialize
        embedded, remote = implementation.initialize(classpath, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/reflection.py", line 44, in initialize
        jvm = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_core.py", line 96, in getDefaultJVMPath
        return _linux.getDefaultJVMPath()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 36, in getDefaultJVMPath
        jvm = _getJVMFromJavaHome()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 55, in _getJVMFromJavaHome
        if os.path.exists(java_home+"/bin/javac") :
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
    ERROR:root:Importing native backends failed.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/__init__.py", line 51, in initialize
        embedded, remote = implementation.initialize(classpath, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/reflection.py", line 44, in initialize
        jvm = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_core.py", line 96, in getDefaultJVMPath
        return _linux.getDefaultJVMPath()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 36, in getDefaultJVMPath
        jvm = _getJVMFromJavaHome()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 55, in _getJVMFromJavaHome
        if os.path.exists(java_home+"/bin/javac") :
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
    ERROR:root:Importing native backends failed.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/__init__.py", line 51, in initialize
        embedded, remote = implementation.initialize(classpath, params)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/reflection.py", line 44, in initialize
        jvm = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_core.py", line 96, in getDefaultJVMPath
        return _linux.getDefaultJVMPath()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 36, in getDefaultJVMPath
        jvm = _getJVMFromJavaHome()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 55, in _getJVMFromJavaHome
        if os.path.exists(java_home+"/bin/javac") :
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

ile "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/__init__.py", line 51, in initialize
    embedded, remote = implementation.initialize(classpath, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/reflection.py", line 44, in initialize
    jvm = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_core.py", line 96, in getDefaultJVMPath
    return _linux.getDefaultJVMPath()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 36, in getDefaultJVMPath
    jvm = _getJVMFromJavaHome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 55, in _getJVMFromJavaHome
    if os.path.exists(java_home+"/bin/javac") :
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
ERROR:root:Importing native backends failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/__init__.py", line 51, in initialize
    embedded, remote = implementation.initialize(classpath, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/reflection.py", line 44, in initialize
    jvm = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_core.py", line 96, in getDefaultJVMPath
    return _linux.getDefaultJVMPath()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 36, in getDefaultJVMPath
    jvm = _getJVMFromJavaHome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 55, in _getJVMFromJavaHome
    if os.path.exists(java_home+"/bin/javac") :
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
ERROR:root:Importing native backends failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/__init__.py", line 51, in initialize
    embedded, remote = implementation.initialize(classpath, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/reflection.py", line 44, in initialize
    jvm = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_core.py", line 96, in getDefaultJVMPath
    return _linux.getDefaultJVMPath()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 36, in getDefaultJVMPath
    jvm = _getJVMFromJavaHome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 55, in _getJVMFromJavaHome
    if os.path.exists(java_home+"/bin/javac") :
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
ERROR:root:Importing native backends failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/__init__.py", line 51, in initialize
    embedded, remote = implementation.initialize(classpath, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Neo4j.py-0.1_SNAPSHOT-py2.7.egg/neo4j/_backend/reflection.py", line 44, in initialize
    jvm = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_core.py", line 96, in getDefaultJVMPath
    return _linux.getDefaultJVMPath()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 36, in getDefaultJVMPath
    jvm = _getJVMFromJavaHome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py", line 55, in _getJVMFromJavaHome
    if os.path.exists(java_home+"/bin/javac") :
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: can you provide your neo4j config in your django settings.py?

Comment: @FelipeCruz: Yes, I will do it today

Comment: @FelipeCruz: Sorry for the delay. Can you tell me what could be wrong here?

Comment: drow, take a look at this `if os.path.exists(java_home+"/bin/javac") :
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'` Looks like when you run your python app, JAVA_HOME is not accessible(or configured) to the user that is actually executing your python code

Answer (score 2):

You can get more verbose information about why the backend couldn't be found by adding this to NEO4J_OPTIONS:

```
NEO4J_OPTIONS = {
    log: True,
}
```

The output from that logging will make it easier to diagnose the actual issue and suggest a fix.

Answer (score 1):

your settings.py looks ok..

Do you have java SDK installed and JAVA_HOME environment variable set to your JDK? (java JRE is not enough)

From Neo4j.py docs:

> In some situations the JPype
>   compilation process might not link
>   with the appropriate JNI headers,
>   resulting in compilation errors. The
>   first thing to note is that JPype
>   needs the JNI headers from a JDK in
>   order to build, it is not enough to
>   only have a JRE installed when
>   building JPype. If the JAVA_HOME
>   environment variable is not set when
>   building JPype the build script
>   (setup.py) of JPype might have
>   problems locating the appropriate JNI
>   headers. If you are building JPype
>   with sudo python setup.py install you
>   might not inherit the JAVA_HOME
>   environment variable into the sudo
>   environment, an easy warkaround is to
>   run python setup.py bdist before
>   install.

Comment: your neo4j instance is running? `$ bin/neo4j start` ?

Comment: can you run this code on python shell successfully ?
`graphdb = neo4j.GraphDatabase('/var/neo4j/neo4django')`

Comment: running on windows or linux? (or macosx) ?

Comment: @FelipeCruz: btw since you were the most helpful (and the only one) I'm awarding you the bounty.

Comment: can you instantiate neo4j database manually setting jvm? 

`graphdb = neo4j.GraphDatabase("/var/neo4j/neo4jdjango",                               classpapath=[], jvm="/usr/lib/jvm.so")`

Comment: @FelipeCruz: I'll give it a go today.

Comment: @FelipeCruz: Nope. I can't find "usr/lib/jvm.so"

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. No matter what I did (on Debian) Python couldn't find the JAVA_HOME environmental variable. The easiest way to fix it, which I presume you can just add this somewhere in Django, is to add these lines -

```
java_home = os.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
if(java_home == None):
    os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk"
```

where the path is the location of the JDK you want to use (it should have folder /bin after it with java and javac programs)

What I also tried was add the location to /etc/bash.bashrc. Which didn't work for me but might for you.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Anyway, that should get you started in the right direction. But now I have another related problem I'm stuck on with no answer for a week now :(